# Plot histogram using two columns (values, counts) in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, histogram

I have a dataframe having multiple columns in pairs: if one column is values then the adjacent column is the corresponding counts. I want to plot a histogram using values as **x** variable and counts as the **frequency**.

For example, I have the following columns:

```
   Age    Counts
   60     1204
   45      700
   21      400
   .       .
   .       .
   34       56
   10      150
```

I want my code to bin the `Age` values  in ten-year intervals between the maximum and minimum values and get the cumulative frequencies for each interval from the `Counts` column and then plot a histogram. Is there a way to do this using matplotlib ?

I have tried the following but in vain:

```
patient_dets.plot(x='PatientAge', y='PatientAgecounts', kind='hist')
```

(patient_dets is the dataframe with 'PatientAge' and 'PatientAgecounts' as columns)

Comment: What `Age` bins do you want? And what do you want to be the frequency of each bin?

Comment: I want to bin the `PatientAge` column in ten year intervals between the maximum and minimum value. And I want the frequencies to come from the `PatientAgecounts` column for each interval.

Answer (score 5):

I think you need [`Series.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.bar.html):

```
patient_dets.set_index('PatientAge')['PatientAgecounts'].plot.bar()
```

[image: graph]

If need bins, one possible solution is with [`pd.cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html):

```
#helper df with min and max ages
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'G':['14 yo and younger','15-19','20-24','25-29','30-34',
                         '35-39','40-44','45-49','50-54','55-59','60-64','65+'], 
                     'Min':[0, 15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65], 
                     'Max':[14,19,24,29,34,39,44,49,54,59,64,120]})

print (df1)
                    G  Max  Min
0   14 yo and younger   14    0
1               15-19   19   15
2               20-24   24   20
3               25-29   29   25
4               30-34   34   30
5               35-39   39   35
6               40-44   44   40
7               45-49   49   45
8               50-54   54   50
9               55-59   59   55
10              60-64   64   60
11                65+  120   65

cutoff = np.hstack([np.array(df1.Min[0]), df1.Max.values])
labels = df1.G.values

patient_dets['Groups'] = pd.cut(patient_dets.PatientAge, bins=cutoff, labels=labels, right=True, include_lowest=True)
print (patient_dets)
   PatientAge  PatientAgecounts             Groups
0          60              1204              60-64
1          45               700              45-49
2          21               400              20-24
3          34                56              30-34
4          10               150  14 yo and younger

patient_dets.groupby(['PatientAge','Groups'])['PatientAgecounts'].sum().plot.bar()
```

[image: graph1]

Answer (score 2):

You can use pd.cut() to bin your data, and then plot using the function plot('bar')

```
import numpy as np
nBins = 10
my_bins = np.linspace(patient_dets.Age.min(),patient_dets.Age.max(),nBins)

patient_dets.groupby(pd.cut(patient_dets.Age, bins =nBins)).sum()['Counts'].plot('bar')
```